# Retrieving command invocation in AWS SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

I am trying to send command to a running ubuntu ec2 instance. I have configured the appropriate role and I have an ssm agent running on the ec2 instance. Using the boto3 SDK I am able to use the `client.send_command()` function to successfully send a shell command and was subsequently able to get the command Id. Now the challenge is polling for the result. I am trying to use the  `client.get_command_invocation()` function but keep getting a `InvocationDoesNotExist` error. I am confident that I am using the correct command ID and instance ID because I have tested these using the AWS CLI as in  `aws ssm list-command-invocations --command-id #### --instance-id i-#####` and this worked. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
`ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
target_id = "i-####"
response = ssm_client.send_command(
            InstanceIds=[
                target_id 
                    ],
            DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
            Comment="Code to run" ,
            Parameters={
                    "commands": ["ls -l"]
                        }
            )
cmd_id= response['Command']['CommandId']
response = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(CommandId=cmd_id, 
InstanceId=target_id)
print(response)`
```

Here is the returned error:
`botocore.errorfactory.InvocationDoesNotExist: An error occurred (InvocationDoesNotExist) when calling the GetCommandInvocation operation`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by adding a time.sleep() call before calling get_command_invocation(). A short delay should be enough.

Comment: Ahhh, Thanks very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Just add these 2 line.

```py
import time
time.sleep(2)
```

Then It'll work properly generally it take only 0.65sec but it's better to give 2 sec. To make it better you can add some cool stuffs like some print statement in for loop and sleep inside it something like that.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me. Check out the API documentation for how to update the default delays and max attempts at [https://boto3.amazonaws.com](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#waiters).

```py
from botocore.exceptions import WaiterError 
ssm_client = boto3.client(
    "ssm",
    region_name=REGION,
    aws_access_key_id=KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET,
)

waiter = ssm_client.get_waiter("command_executed")
try:
    waiter.wait(
        CommandId=commands_id,
        InstanceId=instance_id,
    )
except WaiterError as ex:
    logging.error(ex)
    return
```

Comment: Showing a full example for posterity: 
```
  client = boto3.client('ssm')
  response = run_command_on_ec2_instance(client, command, instance_id)
  command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
  waiter = client.get_waiter("command_executed")
  try:
    waiter.wait(
        CommandId=command_id,
        InstanceId=instance_id,
    ) 
  except WaiterError as ex:
    logging.error(ex)
    return
  print(client.get_command_invocation(CommandId=command_id, InstanceId=instance_id)['StandardOutputContent'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep` does the job 99% of the time. Here is a better way to do this:

```py
MAX_RETRY = 10

get_command_invocation_params = {
    'CommandId': 'xxx',
    'InstanceId': 'i-xxx'
}

for i in range(MAX_RETRY):
    try:
       command_executed_waiter.wait(**get_command_invocation_params)
       break
    except WaiterError as err:
        last_resp = err.last_response
        if 'Error' in last_resp:
            if last_resp['Error']['Code'] != 'InvocationDoesNotExist' or i + 1 == MAX_RETRY:
                raise err
        else:
            if last_resp['Status'] == 'Failed':
                print(last_resp['StandardErrorContent'], file=sys.stderr)
                exit(last_resp['ResponseCode'])
        continue
```